# when i run below code i got a following error . could anyone enlighten why this is being happened?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

```py
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

df1.dtype

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_21492/2172501428.py in <module>
----> 1 df1.dtype

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in __getattr__(self, name)
   5485         ):
   5486             return self[name]
-> 5487         return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
   5488 
   5489     def __setattr__(self, name: str, value) -> None:

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'dtype'
```

Comment: try `df1.info()` which will tell datatype of every column. What you want is `df1[column_name].dtype`

Comment: It is probably dtypes

Comment: It's `df[col].dtype` OR `df.dtypes`

Comment: your missing an 's'.... 'df1.dtypes'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DataFrames have a property called `dtypes`, not `dtype`. See [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html).

Comment: yes!...its works